# jq sorts KEY and VALUES in different way - how can I enumerate them in the same order?

Tags: json, shell, unix, enumeration, jq

I get REST output in JSON format using curl command as below

Getting KEY names alone using:

```
curl http://test.te:8080/testApp/app/version | jq '.version' | jq '. | keys'
```

OUTPUT:

```
"Archiver-Version",
"Build-Id",
"Build-Jdk",
"Build-Number",
"Build-Tag",
"Built-By"
```

Getting VALUES alone using:

```
curl http://test.te.com:8080/testApp/app/version | jq '.version' | jq '.[]'
```

OUTPUT (Note how the order of values doesn't correspond to the order of key names; e.g., the first value, `"user@test.com"`, is the value for key `"Built-By"`, not, as I would expect, for the first key, `"Archiver-Version"`):

```
"user@test.com"
"1634d38"
"sandbox"
"02-03-2014-13:41"
"testApp"
```

I am trying to assign the KEYS and VALUES to separate arrays, so that I can iterate over them and display them in table format.

But these two commands are sorted in different way, I cannot assign the values and keys directly.

Is there anyway to change the sorting of KEYS and VALUES so that both are same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jq has an option to sort the keys. See http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq

```
--sort-keys / -S:

Output the fields of each object with the keys in sorted order.
```

However the current released version (1.3) of jq doesn't have this enhancement yet, you'll need to compile jq via latest code from it's master branch. See http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/ , the "From source on Linux or OS X" section.

For a complete history and details of this feature, see issue #79 "Option or function to sort object members by name" https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/79

Comment: `-S` / `--sort-keys`, which became available in v1.4, only applies to objects _as a whole_, _on output_ - it doesn't affect
how functions and operators such as `keys` and `[]` work, which always enumerate the same way - differently - so it doesn't help here.

Comment: ``-S`` does version sort which ``jq -r 'sort_by(.tag_name) | reverse | .[].tag_name'`` does not. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

The problem stems from `jq`'s possibly surprising **default behavior**:

- `keys` enumerates the keys alphabetically *sorted*.
- `.[]` enumerates the values based on the keys' *input order*<sup>[1]</sup>

In other words: If you use `keys` to extract an object's *keys* in one pass, and then `.[]` to extract its *values* in another, the corresponding output elements might not match.

**`jq` v1.5** introduced the **`keys_unsorted/0`** function, which enables a simple solution:

```
# Sample input with unordered keys.
# Sorting the values results in the same order as sorting the keys,
# so the output order of values below implies the key enumeration order that was applied.
json='{ "c":3, "a":1, "b":2 }'
```

Print ***keys* in input order**, using `keys_unsorted/0`:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -r 'keys_unsorted[]'
c
a
b
```

Print ***values* in input order**, which `[]` invariably does:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -r '.[]'
3
1
2
```

**Caveat**: Up to version **v1.3**, using **`.[]`** resulted in **no guaranteed enumeration order** (the underlying hash table's key sorting was used, which is an implementation detail); if you still must use v1.3, you can use the `to_entries` approach shown below.

---

**[v1.3+]** **`to_entries/0`**, as used in [user2259432's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315502/45375), also enumerates the properties **in input order**:

```
# Extract keys
$ echo "$json" | jq -r 'to_entries | map(.key)[]'
c
a
b
```

```
# Extract values
$ echo "$json" | jq -r 'to_entries | map(.value)[]'
3
1
2
```

**Caveat**: **Prior to v1.5, `to_entries/0`** output key-value pairs in **sorted-by-key order**.

However, since `to_entries/0` can be used to enumerate both keys and values, it is **still a viable solution for producing a stable enumeration order** in parallel key/value extractions, **even in pre-v1.5 versions**.

---

**[v1.3+]** If, by contrast, you want to **enumerate in *sorted-by-key* order**:

Print ***keys* in alphabetically sorted order**, using `keys/0`:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -r 'keys[]'
a
b
c
```

Print ***values* by alphabetically sorted keys**:

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | .[$k]'
1
2
3
```

---

A **caveat re `-S` / `--sort-keys`**:

This option **only applies to *whole objects*, on *output*:**

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -Sc '.'
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}  # Sorted by key
```

It **doesn't apply when you use an operator or function to access the internals of an object:**

```
$ echo "$json" | jq -S '.[]' # !! -S doesn't apply, because [] always uses input order
3
1
2
```

---

<sup>[1] Prior to v1.5, *no particular order* was guaranteed, resulting the same problem, however.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You can also

```
$ echo '{"a":0, "b":1}' | jq -c 'to_entries|map([.key, .value])|map(.[])'
["a",0,"b",1]
```