# jq - using map function to preserve the currently sorted order of properties

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have the following JSON named as *my.json*.

```
[
  {
    "action": "copy",
    "artifact_location": "one foo one"
  },
  {
    "action": "copy",
    "artifact_location": "one bar one"
  },
  {
    "action": "remove",
    "artifact_location": "two foo two"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to understand the usage of the *map function* in ***jq version 1.3***.

Later, I intend the use this logic (i.e. *map function*) for a complex jq filter to preserve the currently sorted order of properties in each object as *--sort-keys* option is **not** available in ***jq version 1.3***.

My goal is to output the content of the *my.json* file as it as after using the map function.

So far, I have come up with the following *jq* command based on the answers [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42324565/5729556) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24315502/5729556).

```
jq -r 'map(to_entries | map({(.key): .value}))' my.json
```

Which gives me the following output.

```
[
  [
    {
      "action": "copy"
    },
    {
      "artifact_location": "one foo one"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "action": "copy"
    },
    {
      "artifact_location": "one bar one"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "action": "remove"
    },
    {
      "artifact_location": "two foo two"
    }
  ]
]
```

If I combine the ***add*** function as follows.

```
jq -r 'map(to_entries | map({(.key): .value}) | add )' my.json
```

It **changes the previously sorted order** of properties similar to the output below.

```
[
  {
    "artifact_location": "one foo one",
    "action": "copy"
  },
  {
    "artifact_location": "one bar one",
    "action": "copy"
  },
  {
    "artifact_location": "two foo two",
    "action": "remove"
  }
]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jq 1.3 makes no guarantees about the ordering of keys within an object. It's really as simple as that, though `map` itself has nothing to do with the reordering you've noticed.

Bear in mind also that that version of jq is very old and should be considered obsolete.

However, within the confines of jq 1.3, you might be able to do whatever it is you are *really* trying to do, but any example of keys being reordered will just illustrate the previous point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I have decided to migrate to the latest version as I don't have another option.